# apply folder rights to other folders powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I need to change a lot of sub folders's ACL rights. The folders all have the same name "06 - Offers". I've found a powershell command to "copy past" the acl rights from one folder to another. I wonder if anybody here can point me in the right direction to automate this?

It would need to search in a defined folder and change all the access rights for a specific folder in each of it's sub folders (if that makes sense).

(Get-Item 'C:\testfolder').GetAccessControl("Access") | Set-Acl -Path 'D:\realfolder'

So for example we have the folders:

D:\project\project1\06offers 
D:\project\project2\06offers 
d:\project\project3\06offers

etc...

And all the 06offers folders need the exact same ACL rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this you should be able to create a solution which fits for you:

```
#Get "example" rights
$PathToExampleFolder = "PathToFile"
$MasterACL = (Get-Item $PathToExampleFolder).GetAccessControl("Access") 

#Search all folders
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "PathWhereTheFoldersAre" -Recurse -Filter "06offers"

#Set ACL
foreach ($folder in $Folders) {
    Set-Acl -Path $folder.Fullname -AclObject $MasterACL
}
```

Comment: Hi works perfectly except one more question, can I disable the inheritence for the sub folder 06offers also via the powershell script?

Comment: You can do that with `$MasterACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true)`. You can easy google it, pleae consider this next time.